# Arraylist of objects - smallest value

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, min

I have an arraylist of objects, and the objects have "double" values. I need to print out all the objects, and have the object with the highest value printed first, and the object with the lowest value last.

I have also tried to use Collections to sort the arraylist and then print, but I can't seem to get it to work.

My arraylist is:

```
ArrayList<Transition> transitions = new ArrayList<Transition>();
```

When i tried to used Collections i used:

```
Object minValue = Collections.min(transitions);
```

Hope some of you can help :)

Comment: Have you tried with Collections.sort()?

Comment: do you need in ascending/ dec order? then use TreeSet http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: Your Transition Class must implement Comparable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Transition object implemented Comparable  interface try this way. It should work.

```
 Collections.sort(transitions);
 Transition transition = transitions.get(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because `Transition` HAS `double` values, doesn't make `Transition` comparable. You must implement a Comparator or define Transition as implements `Comparable` then implement the comparTo() method.  You can compare the two object by that double value.  Then you can use the `sort()` and `min()`

Java does not know how to compare the object unless you tell it how the object are comparable.  Some classes come comparable, like `String` class, `Date`, `Integer`, etc.

**Edit: To make Transition Comparable**

```
public class Transition implements Comparable<Transition> {
    double value;

    public Transition(double value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int compareTo(Transition t){
        if (this.value > t.value) {  // your comparing the Transitionss by the 'value'
            return 1;
        }
        else if (this.value == t.value){
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Transition tranny1 = new Transition(5);
        Transition tranny2 = new Transition(6);

        ArrayList<Transition> trannys = new ArrayList<>();

        trannys.add(tranny1);
        trannys.add(tranny2);

        Collections.sort(trannys);
        double lowTrannyValue = trannys.get(0).value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I do this? I think I somewhat understand what you mean, but I don't know how to do it (quite new at Java).

Comment: @user2795095 I also gave the alternative approach.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you :) I got the code to run now, but it's now in ascending order. I hope I will understand how to fix it. Your answer was very useful :)

Comment: If you want it in different order, just switch the 1 and -1 around in the `compareTo()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Transition> transitions = new ArrayList<Transition>();    
//fill list
Collections.sort(transitions, new Comparator<Transition>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Transition lhs, Transition rhs) {
                    if (lhs.doubleValue > rhs.doubleValue)
                       return 1;
                    if (lhs.doubleValue < rhs.doubleValue)
                       return -1;
                    return 0;
                }
            });

System.out.print(transitions.get(0)); // smallest value
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, if you want to use `Collections.sort()`, you must have `Transition` implement the `Comparable` interface, which means including a `.compareTo()` and modifying your class header to:

```
public class Transition implements Comparable<Transition>
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
Collections.sort(transitions, new Comparator<Transition>() {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Transition t1, Transition t2) {
          return t1.getDoubleValue().compareTo(t2.getDoubleValue());
    }
});
```

where `getDoubleValue()` is just a name that I used to represent a method in your `Transition` class that returns the `Double` that you referenced in your post.  If you don't want to use `Double`, then you could write `.compareTo()` as follows (NB: uses conditional ternary operator in lieu of if statements):

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Transition t1, Transition t2) {
      return t1.getDoubleValue() > t2.getDoubleValue() ? 1 : 
             t1.getDoubleValue() < t2.getDoubleValue() ? -1 : 0;
}
```

Here's a reference for [Object Ordering in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html).