# Get Minimum object based on some fields from a List of objects

Tags: java, android, collections

I'm new in Android development and I'm trying to find the best way to get the minimum object from the object list based on 3 fields. 
I have an object list, each object having 4 fields: `Name`, `State` (int value), `LSeconds` (int value) and `USeconds` (int value).
I want to get the minimum object based first by `State` (minimum State value) and if two or more objects have the same minimum state to check the `LSeconds` value for the find objects and if those are also the same to check by `USeconds` and in the end to return the first one if there are more than one object with the same minimum `State`, minimum `LSeconds` and minimum `USeconds`. Is there a function that can do this automatically or do I need to do it by using the `for`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19970524/2235972

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java 8 you can use [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
Comparator<YourObject> comparator = Comparator.comparing(YourObject::getState)
                         .thenComparing(YourObject::getLSeconds)
                         .thenComparing(YourObject::getUSeconds);
```

Then you can sort your list: `Collections.sort(yourList, comparator);`

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't have this sort function with objects you're looking for. If you use [StreamSupport](https://github.com/streamsupport/streamsupport) Java library though, there's a method you can use, something like this:

```
List<YourObject> result = list.stream().sorted((ob1, ob2)-> ob1.getState().
                               compareTo(ob2.getState())).
                               collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can work with this lambda to apply the logic you're looking for (check `State` first, then `LSeconds`, etc..)

PS: you can do this easily with Kotlin, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259159/sort-collection-by-multiple-fields-in-kotlin)

**EDIT**: Actually, you can with Java 8, sorry.
Check [@mạnh-quyết-nguyễn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8486518/m%E1%BA%A1nh-quy%E1%BA%BFt-nguy%E1%BB%85n) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50374243/6789109).

Comment: You can do it with Java.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, linked your answer on a edit.